# Docker - connection to database on different container

Tags: linux, docker

How do I do a local connection to Postgres on the same server, if the IP address sometimes changes?

I have some docker linux containers running on a standalone linux server, and some of them connect to a Postgres container on the same server - by the IP of the server host along with the port. Sometimes the IP address of the host does change.

I've tried localhost in the connection string, or loopback 127.0.0.1 - but both fail. I would try the servername, but this could conceivably change if I deploy the container to a different box. I'd prefer not to pass to the container as an environment variable, as I'd like the container deployment to be vanilla.

The server host gets an IP from a DHCP server.

The Postgres container has these settings:

"NetworkSettings": {
"Bridge": "",
"SandboxID": "ca868f24636156979444c0bf85ec0c0522f7fae9678ba89086d2799661e919e6",
"HairpinMode": false,
"LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
"LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
"Ports": {
"5432/tcp": [
{
"HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
"HostPort": "5432"
}
]
},

Comment: If you do a docker ps for your postgres container, what is the output? I am curious how the port binding is done.

Comment: Are you allowed to set `network_mode: host` in your docker container's run commands?

Comment: You should specify host names when you start your containers, then connect using the host names. The bridge network driver also lets you specify the subnet to use. If however you decide to use host mode networking you'll be able to publish the ports from your container to localhost and connect to them.

Comment: Have you considered using `docker-compose` which allows you to access database server by hostname instead of IP ?